# aws dynamo db get rid of datatype in response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a sample table in AWS Dynamo DB.

When I am trying to read items from it by using Lambda, in the response am seeing additional data types from dynamo db.

is there any way we can avoid them ?

```
 [{
"year": {
  **"S":** "2018"
},
"state": {
  **"S"**: "NSW"
}},{"year": {
  **"S":** "2017"
},
"state": {
  **"S"**: "NSW"
} }]
```

I don't want to have **"S"** in response.

I would like to have response like this.

{"year": "2018"}

This will be possible ?

Comment: Which language is the code in?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: My lambda code is in nodejs

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NodeJS, you can use the [AWS DynamoDB DocumentClient SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html), instead of the core SDK to do the queries. This will simplify both querying and the results.

However for other languages that doesn't have the Document Client SDK, you need to write your own wrapper to parse and filter the types from query results.

Comment: Other languages have their SDK too

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the following code to convert in to readable json format without unwanted datatypes
                Document doc = Document.FromAttributeMap(item);
                string documentresp = doc.ToJson();

Answer (score 0):

Just change the SDK for Dynamo DB
Use `aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()` instead of `AWS.DynamoDB();`.

Comment: For inline-code I'd highly suggest using the ` syntax - for a small formatting/markdown guide click [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).